# Can't find TWTestCommandPackageGuids.cs file mentioned in walkthrough of VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am following this walkthrough:
[MSDN Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164714.aspx)

But I can't find the TWTestCommandPackageGuids.cs file in my project, and so I can't add the following lines to it:

```
public const string guidTWTestCommandPackageCmdSet = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000";  // get the GUID from the .vsct file
public const int TWToolbar = 0x1000;
```

It doesn't seem as if I should create the file though. Where should I then add the above lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file should be added when you add the menu command to your project. If it didn't, there's no big deal -- that file it's asking for is just a C# file with constants. You can put it wherever you want (or just create a new file.)

Comment: Thanks I just created a new file and put the constants in there.